# Observable's subscribe is never triggered

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm facing an strange behavior while subscribing to my Observable.
For some reason the `console.log(item)` is never called and also there are no errors on the console.

```
this.store$
.pipe(
  select(getRecentNotes),
  mergeAll(),
  groupBy(item => item.status.code),
  mergeMap(group => group.pipe(toArray())),
  toArray()
)
.subscribe((items)=> console.log('Grouped Items', items));
```

BTW, If I pipe **only** `select(getRecentNotes)` then it works and I'm getting something like this:

```
[
  {id: 1, note: "ABC", status: {code: 1, name: 'active'}},
  {id: 2, note: "DEF", status: {code: 1, name: 'active'}},
  {id: 3, note: "HIJ", status: {code: 2, name: 'hidden'}}
]
```

more interesting is that the following will work:

```
// This will work
this.store$
.pipe(
  select(getRecentNotes),
  mergeAll()
)
.subscribe((items)=> console.log('Bunch of Items', items));
```

But if I add another operator, like toArray() then it stops working.

```
// This will not work
this.store$
.pipe(
  select(getRecentNotes),
  mergeAll(),
  toArray()
)
.subscribe((items)=> console.log('All items', items));
```

Is there any hidden rule that I'm missing out?
I've tried to recreate the problem at StackBlitz using just a simple `Observable.from([])` but everything seems to works.

**Update 1:**
I added some other operators to the pipe, they do stuff (like printing to the console). But the code in the .subscribe is not called

```
this.store$
.pipe(
  select(getRecentNotes),
  mergeAll(),
  tap((item)=> {console.log(item)}),   // <--- This is printed to the console
  reduce((acc, item)=> {
  console.log(acc);                    // <-- This is printed to the console
  console.log(item);
  return acc.push(item);
  },[]) 
)
.subscribe((items)=> console.log('All items', items));
```

Comment: If you add a tap operator instead a toArray() operator does it work?

Comment: I don't know the context of your code but toArray() only works for a finite stream. You cannot use toArray() in a stream that's not closed. You can use either zip or scan to put items into an array from an infinite stream.

Comment: @Robertgarcia I'll check that.

Comment: @AnjilDhamala, yup, that's the kind of rule I'm looking for, probably the issue is there.

Comment: As you can see, without toArray you are already getting ressponse as an array, why are you trying to do toArray() on top of an array

Comment: @yanky_cranky That was just for testing purposes, thing is that it should work either way.

Comment: @Robertgarcia, tap() works and also reduce() works, I mean, the operators runs and do stuff, but the console.log(items) in the .subscribe is not called.

Comment: @AnjilDhamala, is the same for reduce()? I mean, it only works with a finite stream?

Comment: reduce collects items and emits once complete... try scan instead as scan is the analogue for a non terminating stream

Comment: you need to make clear if you're expecting to display the combined results from multiple stream emissions, or if you want to display results from a single stream emission at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @AnjilDhamala mentioned in his comment, operators like `toArray` don't execute until the stream completes.  Your store$ observable stays open for changes so that `toArray` operator will never emit a result.

It seems like your goal is to return an array of arrays chunked by a code?

The simple solution would be to add `take(1)` after your `select` operator call.  That should result in the last `toArray` returning an array of arrays.

But if my assumption is correct, then all of this may be unnecessary.  It might seem that using all those rxjs operators is clean, but the intention of what you're trying to accomplish is far from clear.  After the `select` you can just call `map` with a function that will chunk your array up with plain old JavaScript.

```
this.store$
.pipe(
  select(getRecentNotes),
  map(x => chunkBy(x, x => x.status.code))
).subscribe((items)=> console.log('All items', items));

function chunkBy<T>(ary: T[], chunkKeySelector: (item: T) => any) {
  const result: T[][] = [];
  const indexMap = new Map<any, number>();

  for (let value of ary) {
    const key = chunkKeySelector(value);
    (indexMap.has(key)) 
      ? result[indexMap.get(key)].push(value)
      : indexMap.set(key, result.push([value]) - 1);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: I'll try it. In the end, all I want is a grouped collection of notes using the status.code as grouping criteria.

Comment: @JoseGuzman but is that grouping dependent on MULTIPLE stream items or a SINGLE stream item? if multiple, you'll need some kind of scan operator, or possibly groupBy could work, but groupBy is a weird operator.  if it's single, then you just need map and a synchronous grouping function

Comment: Well, initially is a single stream item because after calling select(getRecentNotes) I'm getting just a single array with the objects, but then I want to iterate object by object so I can group them. So my approach was to call mergeAll() so I can get the objects one by one and group them whether by using groupBy() or reduce()

Comment: @JoseGuzman you're stull being unclear. so do you want to combine and then iterate the arrays from MULTIPLE emissions, or do you just want to iterate the array from ONE emission

Comment: @bryan60 Iterate the array from ONE emission.

Comment: @JoseGuzman then this is the answer you want, just use the map operator. treat a single emission like a single emission. don't force it to be a stream when its not

Comment: Probably this will work. But the mystery remains unsolved, why what's inside the subscribe is not called?

Comment: @JoseGuzman It's not called because toArray() was holding up your stream. It was waiting on the stream to complete.